# How to make JSTL-spring generate clean HTML code?

Tags: spring, jstl

I'm beginning to work with JSTL-spring. It's wonderful, however I need to review the HTML code that it generates. I have a method that appends to a string all the HTML code, so when I `<c:out>` the string it prints one big line, the browser interprets it fine, but not me, and I need to, to accurately debug and make a clean code.

In other words I need linebreaks for the HTML string, not linebreaks for the interpreted html (not `<br>` tag). I tried `/n` but it just prints `/n`. Here is code example:

```
productThumbnails+="<div class=\"prod_box\">";
    productThumbnails+="<div class=\"top_prod_box\"></div>";
    productThumbnails+="<div class=\"center_prod_box\">";
        productThumbnails+="<div class=\"product_title\"><a href=\"details.html\">"+productTemp.getProductName()+"</a></div>";
        productThumbnails+="<div class=\"product_title\"><a href=\"details.html\">"+productTemp.getProductModel()+"</a></div>";
        productThumbnails+="<div class=\"product_img\"><a href=\"details.html\"><img width=\"90\" alt=\""+productTemp.getProductName()+"\" src=\""+productTemp.getProductImage()+"\"/></a></div>";
    productThumbnails+="</div>";
productThumbnails+="</div>";
```

In the view, I print everything with:

```
<c:out value="${productThumbnails}" escapeXml="false" />
```

Comment: your question isn't too clear - are you trying to print the HTML code for a certain page that is rendered? and you don't want the HTML code to be processed by the browser?

Comment: no, i want the html code that irs finally generated to be readable by me, cause the way im doing it, it pastes everything in a single line, i when i want to check it for errors it takes to long.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways:

1. *This is actually servletcontainer specific, but based on your question history you're using Tomcat*. Add the following initialization parameter to the `JspServlet` entry in `Tomcat/conf/web.xml`.

   ```
   <init-param>
       <param-name>trimSpaces</param-name>
       <param-value>true</param-value>
   </init-param>
   ```

   This way any whitespace which is left by taglibs (JSTL and so on) will be trimmed. This is not perfect, but generally sufficient. This does however not cover HTML which is written in the wrong place (i.e. not in JSP).
2. Use [`jTidyFilter`](http://jtidy.sourceforge.net/multiproject/jtidyservlet/filter.html). Drop [jtidyservlet.jar](http://jtidy.sourceforge.net/nightly/jtidyservlet-r8-SNAPSHOT.jar) in `/WEB-INF/lib` and declare the filter in your `Webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml` as per [its documentation](http://jtidy.sourceforge.net/multiproject/jtidyservlet/filter.html).

---

Coming back to the comment that you're approaching this wrong: the proper approach would be to put `List<Product>` in the request scope (if necessary by a Spring bean) and use JSTL `<c:forEach>` to iterate over it.

```
<c:forEach items="${products}" var="product">
    ...
    <div class="center_prod_box">
        <div class="product_title"><a href="details.html"><c:out value="${product.productName}" /></a></div>
        <div class="product_title"><a href="details.html"><c:out value="${product.productModel}" /></a></div>
        <div class="product_img"><a href="details.html"><img width="90" alt="${product.productName}" src="${product.productImage}"/></a></div>
    </div>
    ...
</c:forEach>
```

That yields more clean and better maintainable code (and HTML output ;) ).

Comment: Wow! Great answers, the 3 of them! thanK You! Have a question, JspServlet... im not using that, i only have on my web.xml a dispatcher servlet, that calls jstlViewResolver. Any way i can use the trimSpaces on it ? also im wondering, wont the jTidyFilter make me some how lazy ? and i have a little fear that it wont be maintained in the future or that it will make slower app, what are your thoughts about that ? I think the 3erd and main solution is the best, however i would like to have the view components a little more uncouple, disconnected, cause it will be getting complicated as it evolves.

Comment: The `JspServlet` is in the `web.xml` of the servletcontainer itself, not of your webapp. In Tomcat it's located in `/conf/web.xml` folder of Tomcat installation. As to jTidyFilter, I don't know. I've never used it since it doesn't make much sense to me to format HTML output nicely :) All my HTML is already formatted nicely in JSP.